# Angular UI datepicker popup with type-in returns one date earlier than typed in protractor

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, testing, angular-ui, protractor

This is a bit complicated, but I've now verified it with both Angular Scenario tester and Protractor, and in the user interface.

1. Set up Twitter Bootstrap 3.x (I'm using the latest but had 3.0.3 before) - from the bower boostrap install
2. Set up Angular UI with the built-in templates (I'm using the angular-ui-bootstrap-bower library from Bower)
3. Set up a datepicker-popup field in Angular-UI like this:

   ```
   <label for='due_date'>Due Date</label>
   <input id='due_date'
          class='form-control'
          type='text'
          datepicker-options="dateOptions"
          datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd'
          ng-model="task.dueDate">
   ```
4. Add a button and a controller method to inspect the variable.

Testing:

1. Click on the date field, and type in a date:  2013-01-05
2. Hit escape or click on another field to close the popup dialog (i.e. don't click Done)
3. Submit the form

You'll find the date to be one day behind.

Interestingly, if you click on an actual date in the date picker, it will be correct. Including 'today'.  If I remove the ui datepicker, it works fine with persisting the typed-in data. My date format is YYYY-MM-DD when I type it in.

This is maddening, as I've thought it was a bug in Angular Scenario, but once I figured out that Protractor ALSO fails, and that I could reproduce it by canceling the dialog, and even typing and submitting, I am beginning to think it has something to do with localization and timezones.

Anyone else run into this?

Here is a protractor test that fails:

```
  it('should return one task', function () {
    thePage.clearTasksButton.click();
    thePage.newTaskButton.click();
    thePage.taskDescription.clear();
    thePage.taskDescription.sendKeys('A new task');

    thePage.taskPriority.clear();
    thePage.taskPriority.sendKeys('1');

    thePage.dueDate.clear();
    // pick today and dismiss the Angular DatePicker
    thePage.todayButton.click();

    thePage.createTaskButton.click();

    var task = element.all(by.repeater('task in tasks').row(0).column('dueDate'));

    task.then(function(elems) {
      // should result in one row
      expect(elems.length).toEqual(1);  // this works
      expect(elems[0].getText()).toEqual('2014-03-19'); // this is 2014-03-18
    });
    ...
```

Thanks

Ken

Comment: Without knowing it deeply: if you come from a Java developer background, this is quite common as there the months run from 0-11 and not as someone might expect from 1-12. Maybe this is the case in your problem also - but just within the days "scope" of the datepicker-ui component? I didn't investigate that, it is just a short guess...

Comment: If it was the month, then I'd agree. It's literally one day off. So I've tried 03-20-2014 and it came back as 03-19-2014. Strange. But only if I didn't use the picker to 'click' on the date.

Comment: It's even easier to reproduce. Follow this plunk:  

http://plnkr.co/edit/NGFeNlR2WvF2TjwZNc4x?p=preview

Comment: Curious if you ever found a solution as im having the same problem.  Strangely your plunker is working now?

Comment: By testing it manually I can reproduce so this is not Protractor issue but datepicker one.